# I am unable to show output value from database in ejs?

Tags: express, mongoose, ejs

**My ejs for loop where variables comes from backend:**

<% photolist.forEach(function(photo){ %>

```
                            <tr id="<%=photo.id %>" class="gradeX">
                                <td> <a href="/PhotoContestUploads/<%=photo.Photo%>" data-lightbox="example-set"
                                        data-title="<%=photo.Description%>"><img
                                            src="/PhotoContestUploads/<%= photo.Photo %>"
                                            style="width:100px; height:50px;"> </a></td>


                                <td name="author"><%= photo.Name %>

                                </td>
                                <td>Win 95+</td>


                                <% if ( photo.done  ){ %>

                                <td class="center"> Selected</td>

                                <%  } else { %>

                                <td class="center"> Not Selected</td>

                                <%  } %>


                                <td>

                                    <% if (!photo.done ){ %>

                                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm mr-1 mark-complete-btn "
                                        id="<%=photo.id %>"> Select as winner</i></button>

                                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm mr-1 edit-btn " id="<%=photo.id %>"> <i
                                            class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>

                                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mr-1 delete-btn " id="<%=photo.id %>">
                                        Delete</i></button>

                                   
                                    <% } %>

                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <%})%>
```

Here in IF condition I am not able to show out as per boolian condition from backend. I am storing either true or false in "done" in photo list. When i am using in if condition it is always showing not selected in fronted irrespective data stored in data base.